# What is the difference b/t Default Android Scrolling functionality VS ScrollView / Nested Scrollview?

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview

I realize in android apps... we in Default have the functionality of being able to scroll through the different views and widgets in app we make.

So How does using a Scroll View differ from using the regular feature of being able to scroll through widgets (if we have many text views, edit text, button that take up more than screen).

** Also when, a "Good use case" should we use it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure most viewgroups aren't scrollable by default even when their children overflow, can you perhaps post a reproducible sample?

Comment: Most activities don't scroll, so if you want the screen to scroll you have to make it <ScrollView>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ScrollView` is like a little window you can scroll up and down so you can see all its content - it can be any size on the screen. Like @Marrows says, by default nothing scrolls - if a widget is off the screen, it's off the screen!

So if your layout requires stuff that might not all fit - say because there's a variable amount of it, or things can expand (like a large text field), or because on smaller screens (or in landscape) there's potentially not enough room - you need to explicitly allow for some or all of your UI to scroll by putting it in a scroll view.

One typical way to do this is to have fixed items at the top and bottom of the screen, and put a scrollview in the rest of the space. That way, if there's room to display all its contents at once, great! Otherwise if it gets squished, the user can still scroll its display and access everything.

The layout inside the `ScrollView` needs to be big enough to hold all its content (usually `wrap content`) otherwise stuff will get cut off as usual. The scroll view itself defines how big the window into that layout is. That larger layout just moves up and down behind it.

A `RecyclerView` is a type of `ScrollingView` which is why you might have thought it was typical behaviour (and `TextView`s allow you to scroll inside them too, if they're smaller than their contents)

Answer (score 1):

Most activities don't scroll, so if you want the screen to scroll you have to make it .

An example is that you use a huge screen size for your app AVD, but when you try to use it in smaller phones, only a few inputs/infos will appear because the Activity isn't scrolling.

Check the android community for more info, it's the best thing to do when you're starting
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView

Comment: Thank you all for those rather Quick and helpful replies :) I have not tried it but I assumed as I was learning about Scroll view. --- This was my first Stackoverflow questions and happy with the feedbacks